# EXCEL: Return a value from table if two criteria are met. One is a date range

Tags: if-statement, match, vlookup

Here is my dilemma. I have a column in one table that is blank. to fill it I need to look up user id in another table, and return a value from that table, but if and only if the the date from the 1st table falls within the range of dates from two columns in the 2nd table.

1. Look up userid in sheet 2
2. If found look up transdate trans date must fall on or between
   placefromdt and placetodate
3. If criteria 1 and 2 met return the value in place

I tried to post pictures of the sheets but I am not authorized.  Here is an abbreviated look

**UserID        TransDate   Place**

93696732A   12/01/2014
99898585F   12/01/2014
99898585F   11/01/2014
91867459C   12/01/2014
91867459C   11/01/2014
91867459C   10/01/2014
91867459C   09/01/2014
91867459C   08/01/2014
91867459C   07/01/2014

```
userid      station placeid place    placefrmdt  placetodt

E13332190   HW      105612  STJWCC   09/01/2014  02/28/2015
A97059190   HW      105614  TCI      01/01/2014  12/31/9999
A56586039   HW      105614  TCI      01/01/2014  12/31/9999
C02409039   HW      107549  USCEFSGA 12/01/2014  01/31/2015
C67974990   HW      107539  KH       05/01/2015  12/31/9999
C99804409   HW      105612  STJWCC   01/01/2015  04/30/2015
C59064990   HW      105611  SBFHG    08/01/2014  04/30/2015
F09035309   HW      107540  LAC      07/01/2014  12/31/9999
D49047905   HW      105612  STJWCC   10/01/2014  01/31/2015
D13929089   HW      107549  USCEFSGA 09/01/2014  01/31/2015
```

Comment: From the tags, it appears that you are looking for an Excel formula and not VBA, is that correct?

Comment: Either would work.  I'm just not as familiar with VBA

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using MATCH + INDEX, as an array function.
Note: when entering an array function in Excel, do not press ENTER after entering the function.  Press Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead, so Excel knows to treat this as an array function.

Given the following Excel worksheets:

[image: Sheet 1]

Sheet 1

[image: Sheet 2]

Sheet2

The formula for the Place column on Sheet1 is

```
 =INDEX(Sheet2!A:F,MATCH(1,(Sheet2!A:A=A2)*(Sheet2!E:E<=B2)*(Sheet2!F:F>=B2),0),4)
```

To break this down:

INDEX has 3 parameters.

The first parameter is the table that you want to retrieve data from, Sheet2!A:F

The second parameter is the row number, which we are calculating using MATCH

The third parameter is the column number, 4, which corresponds to the Place column in Sheet2

MATCH has three parameters.

The first parameter is the value to match, in this case 1

The second parameter is the table to match it to, which we are calculating

The third parameter is what type of match, in this case 0, for exact match.

For the second parameter of MATCH, we are using (Sheet2!A:A=A2)*(Sheet2!E:E<=B2)*(Sheet2!F:F>=B2).  Logically translated, this is the set of all cells where column A = A2 and column E <= B2 and column F >= B2.  Each of these individual items would return a true/false, but when you perform math functions with true/false in Excel, it converts the true/false to 1/0. So for the row where all three conditions are true, this will return a 1, and the rest of the rows will return 0.  Since we supplied 1 as the value that MATCH was trying to match, this will return the row number where all three conditions are true.